# Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

when i do composer update t my laravel project 
and after run any api this error appear

```
Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)
```

this is my composer.json file

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "astrotomic/laravel-translatable": "^11.1",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.26",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^3.17",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^5.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.37",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
```

and this my php version :

```
PHP 7.3.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick Google brought me to this issue on the Laravel repo: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30655#issuecomment-558619927.

> Had the same issue, quickest fix is to require `"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"` in your `composer.json` & run `composer update`

However this shouldn't be needed since the most likely cause is because locally you are using PHP `7.3` but where you get the error another PHP version is running, for example `7.2`.

If that is the case you can run this command `composer config platform.php 7.2` (replace `7.2` with `7.1` if that is the version you need) to tell composer which PHP version you are targeting, that allows you to use `7.3` locally but packages will be installed for the correct PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error while doing upgrades from an old version of Laravel to a new one, it could be that the file TranslatorInterface.php is present in the translation folder. Rename it or remove it and see if that helps. It did for me.